# I get an error saying "The method compare(String, String) is undefined for the type String" Why can't I sort my 2D array?

Tags: java, string, sorting, comparator

I am working on a jeopardy GUI game where I sort my 2d array of questions. I get an error on the .compare line where I return. The error says "The method compare(String, String) is undefined for the type String"

```
       JButton btnSort = new JButton("Sort");
            btnSort.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

                 String[][] questions = new String[][] { {"How many continents are there?"}, {"What is the capital of Canada?"}, {"What is the largest country in the world?"}, {"What is the largest ocean in the world?"}, {"How many oceans are there in the world?"}, {"How many countries make up Africa?"}, {"How many countries in the world begin with the word United?"}, {"Where is Milan?"}, {"What is the least populated US state?"}, {"What is the capital of Australia?"}, {"How many countries begin with the letter J?"}, {"Which country has the most lakes in the world?"}};


                            java.util.Arrays.sort(questions, new java.util.Comparator<String[]>() {
                                public int compare(String[] a, String[] b) {
                                    return String.compare(a[0], b[0]);
                                }
                            });

                }
            });
```

Comment: Why do you believe `String` has a `compare` method? The **documentation**, i.e. the javadoc of [`String`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/13/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/String.html#method.summary) doesn't show such a method. Use `return a[0].compareTo(b[0]);`

Comment: The relevance of [tag:arrays] and [tag:user-interface] escapes me.

Answer (score 2):

Because [`String.compareTo(String)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#compareTo-java.lang.String-) is **not** a `static` method taking two parameters (**and** is not named *compare*). It's an instance method that can compare one `String` instance with another; Like,

```
java.util.Arrays.sort(questions, new java.util.Comparator<String[]>() {
    public int compare(String[] a, String[] b) {
        return a[0].compareTo(b[0]);
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

It is because you are using compare method as static method. Use it like any other instance method. You can even use compareTo().

Comment: `String.compare()` doesn't exist, either as a static or an instance method.

Comment: I am not saying to use it as compare() method of string class, because it doesn't exist. What I am saying is use compare() as instance method of comparator class. Moreover, we can also use compareTo() of comparable class.